# Getting minimun data from a column Panda Dataframe and adding column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas Serie.

```
    XAMS    [6.2965, 6.297, 6.298]
    XPAR    [6.2963, 6.297, 6.298]
    Name: 1, dtype: object
```

What I want to obtain is the following Dataframe or something that can perform this result.

```
         XPAR     XPAR/XAMS     XPAR/XAMS
XAMS    [6.2963,      6.297,     6.298]
```

The idea is to get the minimun value and also obtaining what are the serie it refers that value.

With the min function I obtain the previous result but I dont have what colum it refers to.

My code:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    data_aux = row.dropna()
    if (side == Quote.FIELD_PX_BID):
        best = data_aux.min()
    else:
        best = data.max()
```

Where data_aux is the first pandas Dataframe I want to check.

Comment: Does a cell of the dataframe contain a list ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. Yes, it can contain a list

Comment: Are the lenghts of these lists equals?

Comment: @Valetino In this case there are equal, but It can be not equal, in the case there is a list with 2 values and other with 3 for example, the third result would be from the list that there is a value

Comment: It seems your data are not [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so `min` of all values working nice. Is it correct? If not, is possible change data when are min and also max counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need minimimum first values, second and similar of lists use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['FIELD_PX_BID'].values.tolist()).min().to_frame().T
print (df)
        0      1      2
0  6.2963  6.297  6.298
```

**Details**:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df['FIELD_PX_BID'].values.tolist()))
        0      1      2
0  6.2965  6.297  6.298
1  6.2963  6.297  6.298
```

If there are maximum length of list 3 is possible specify columns names:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(df['FIELD_PX_BID'].values.tolist(), 
                   columns=['XPAR','XPAR/XAMS','XPAR/XAMS']).min().to_frame().T)
print (df)
     XPAR  XPAR/XAMS  XPAR/XAMS
0  6.2963      6.297      6.298
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df[0].apply(pd.Series).apply(min, axis=1)
```

Explanations:

1. transform the `list` to dataframe columns
2. Apply the `min` on columns

```
# Your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[[6.2965, 6.297, 6.298],
                  [6.2963, 6.297, 6.298], 
                  [6.2963, 6.297, 6.298,  6.298],
                  [6.2963, 6.297 ]]},
                  index=['XAMS', 'XPAR', 'XPAR2', 'XPAR3'])
print(df)
#                                    0
# XAMS          [6.2965, 6.297, 6.298]
# XPAR          [6.2963, 6.297, 6.298]
# XPAR2  [6.2963, 6.297, 6.298, 6.298]
# XPAR3                [6.2963, 6.297]

# Transform the list to new columns
df = df[0].apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
#             0      1      2      3
# XAMS   6.2965  6.297  6.298    NaN
# XPAR   6.2963  6.297  6.298    NaN
# XPAR2  6.2963  6.297  6.298  6.298
# XPAR3  6.2963  6.297    NaN    NaN

# Apply the `min` operator each cloumns
df_min = df.apply(min, axis=1)
print(df_min)
# XAMS     6.2965
# XPAR     6.2963
# XPAR2    6.2963
# XPAR3    6.2963
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that `sr` is your `Series`, I create here a series with different lengths to show that it works in this case too:

```
sr = pd.Series([[6.2965, 6.297], [6.2963, 6.297, 6.298]], index=['XAMS', 'XPAR'])
```

You can do:

```
res_sr = pd.DataFrame(ss.to_list(), columns=['XPAR','XPAR/XAMS','XPAR/XAMS']).min()
```

`res_sr` is a `Series`:

```
XPAR         6.2963
XPAR/XAMS    6.2970
XPAR/XAMS    6.2980
dtype: float64
```

If you need to shape it in the form of a dataframe with a row (as in your question), do:

```
res_sr.to_frame().transpose()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I may have a solution.

```
d       = []
frame   = []

d = list(map(list,zip(XAMS, XPAR)))
```

This piece of code puts your values in this fashion:

```
[[6.2965, 6.2963], [6.297, 6.297], [6.298, 6.298]]
```

Then you can get the minimums you wanted to:

```
for pairs in d:

minimal = (min(pairs))
frame.append(minimal)
```

Use the result of frame to build your dataframe.

I hope it helps.